# Extract only the body text of the PDF, not the bulleted points, headings and subheadings using python pdfplumber library

Tags: python, text-extraction, pypdf, pdf-scraping, pdfplumber

**Code**

```
import pdfplumber

ecdata = ""

with pdfplumber.open("XYZ Transcript.pdf") as pdf:
    for i in range(len(pdf.pages)):
        print("Page No.: ", i+1)
        page_obj = pdf.pages[i]
        page = page_obj.within_bbox((70, 50, page_obj.width, 790))
        ecpagedata = page.extract_text()
        ecdata += ecpagedata
        print(page.extract_text())
```

[Output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJIzs.png)

**The output required should only contain complete sentences of the file and not the unwanted bullets, headings and subheadings**

Good day, and thank you for standing by. Welcome to the XYZ Second Quarter 2099
Earnings Conference Call. At this time, all participants are in a listen-only mode. After the
speakers' presentation, there will be a question-and-answer session. (Operator
Instructions) Please be advised that today's conference is being recorded.

I would now like to hand the conference over to your speaker today, Alpha, Vice President
of Investor Relations. Please go ahead.

Thank you, operator. Good afternoon and welcome to XYZ’s second quarter 2022
earnings call. I'm joined today by Bravo, XYZ’s Founder and CEO; and Charlie, our CFO.
Full details of our results and additional management commentary are available in our
shareholder letter, which can be found on our Investor Relations website at
website.com/investor. Our comments and responses to your questions on this call reflect
management's views as of today only and we disclaim any obligation to update this
information. On this call, we'll make forward-looking statements which are predictions,
projections, or other.

**I am attaching the image of the PDF file here**

[Source file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgcwl.png)

*The source image file is my own creation and does not directly or indirectly represent any entity real or fictitious whatsoever.*

Comment: This is obviously homework.  You need to make a good faith effort to solve this yourself before coming to us with help.  Hint: how can you identify a bullet point?  How can you identify a heading?

Comment: Why don't you share the pdf file directly?